# java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to load json data into a scrollable spinner. But I am getting the error that the CustomAdapter is not able to cast into ArrayAdapter. Can you help me with this?

Provide_Food.xml: This is the file where the spinner is located

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grdnt"
    tools:context=".Provide_food">

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/select_food"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="@color/bgcolor"
        app:hintText="Select Item"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select_food_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/select_food"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Add Item"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Provide_Food.java: The java class for loading the json data into the spinner

```
package com.example.helping_hands_individual;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextLinks;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.Nullable;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Provide_food extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    String url = "api_link"; //can't mention the link here
    List<Item_Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_provide_food);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.select_food);


        new Getdata().execute();
    }

    class Getdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        String result;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Provide_food.this, list);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL mainurl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)mainurl.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                result = builder.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                    Item_Model item_model = new Item_Model();
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String itemname = object.getString("Item Name");
                    item_model.setItemname(itemname);
                    list.add(item_model);
                }
            }
             catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

}
```

Item_Model.java: The model class for getting the item name from the json api

```
package com.example.helping_hands_individual;

public class Item_Model {

    String itemname;

    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java: The custom adapter used for parsing the data into the spinner

```
package com.example.helping_hands_individual;

import android.content.Context;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    List<Item_Model> list;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Item_Model> list){
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
        TextView itemname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_names);

        itemname.setText(list.get(i).itemname);

        return view;
    }
}
```

item.xml: The sample layout file where it contains only the textview which will be displayed in the spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_names"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Demo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: CustomAdapter need to extend ArrayAdapter

Comment: What needs to be added in the super() method in the constructor then?

Comment: ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)

Comment: But the constructor does not pass any resource

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomAdapter` should extends `ArrayAdapter`, so you can change your class in this way:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    List<Item_Model> list;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int resources, List<Item_Model> list) {
        super(applicationContext, resources);
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    //...

}
```

Consider using the parameterized `ArrayAdapter<T>` feature